# Rspec / Capybara issues -- Capybara won't visit page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

Ok so I'm kinda new, but have somewhat of an idea of what I'm doing, but this one just has me stumped for the past couple hours, so any help is very much appreciated.  I'm building a site and have been using Rspec and Capybara to test my site as I'm moving along. I ended up needing to remove turbolinks to improve functionality for my jscripts.  The next time I try to run tests, literally 50% of my test suite just magically broke. I've narrowed it down to that the commonality between all the failures was that the "visit" either appeared in or just before the code block. So basically removing Turbolinks somehow blew Capybara up or Rspec. I'm really having some trouble figuring this one out.  I tried updating the gems, that didn't work. I guess the next step is either skip the TDD concept, which I don't want to do, or start uninstalling the gems and do a reinstall and pray that that doesn't render my app useless...  Any help anyone can provide is much appreciated, and if you're in NYC I'll buy you a beer.

There are also other tests that are failing that don't require any sort of authentication, just to check the page for title and content and those are failing to.  I bring that up only to say I don't think that FactoryGirl is causing the problem.

Cheers.

The errors

```
2) User pages profile page                                                                                                                                                                  
 Failure/Error: before { visit user_path(user) }                                                                                                                                          
 NoMethodError:                                                                                                                                                                           
   undefined method `user_path' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UserPages::ProfilePage:0x00000004290410>                                                                                      
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'                                                                                                        

3) User pages profile page                                                                                                                                                                  
 Failure/Error: before { visit user_path(user) }                                                                                                                                          
 NoMethodError:                                                                                                                                                                           
   undefined method `user_path' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UserPages::ProfilePage:0x00000004207c00>                                                                                      
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'                                                                                                        

4) User pages signup page                                                                                                                                                                   
 Failure/Error: before { visit signup_path }                                                                                                                                              
 NameError:                                                                                                                                                                               
   undefined local variable or method `signup_path' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UserPages::SignupPage:0x000000041b3088>                                                                   
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The test suite code

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do 

subject { page }

#Profile tests
describe "profile page" do 
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_content(user.name) }
    it { should have_title(user.name) }
end 

#Signup page tests
describe "signup page" do 
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_content('Sign up') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Sign up')) }
end 

describe "signup" do 

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do 
        it "should not create a user" do 
            expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
        end 
    end 

    describe "with valid information" do 
        before do
            fill_in "Name",                 with: "Example User" 
            fill_in "Email",                with: "user@example.com"
            fill_in "Password",             with: "foobar00"
            fill_in "Confirmation",         with: "foobar00" 
        end 

        it "should create a user" do 
            expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
                end
           end 
      end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

try to remove your visiting pages from before blocks  .

So , you just need :

```
describe "signup page" do 
  feature "should have content 'Sign up' "
   visit signup_path  
   it { should have_content('Sign up') }
  end
  feature "should have full title 'Sign up' "
   visit signup_path  
   it { should have_title(full_title('Sign up')) }
  end
end
```

And you need to do like this in every describe block  .

Comment: Hello zauzaj can you help me with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461462/wicked-pdf-side-issue

Comment: zauzaj thank you for the reply.  While this does do the job, it has considerably lengthened my test suite overall.  Can you provide any insight on why removing Turbolinks would break the test suite the way it did?  All of these tests were passing green prior to removing Turbolinks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so to anyone else that runs into this issue, I did some more digging it's not a so uncommon occurrence for Capybara to get weird at times.  But I got the route errors to fix and pass green by adding "config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers" to the spec_helper.rb file.

```
Rspec.configure do |config|
*
*
* 
config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

end

Unfortunately I can't provide any insight why that line needed to be added, when previously it was not needed.  I'll have to leave that answer to someone with more knowledge than myself.

Comment: I'd guess that it has to do with what you're requiring in your spec_helper.rb/rails_helper.rb. Might want to add your Gemfile and helper(s) to the question.